# Künneth formula for local cohomology with support

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, sheaf-cohomology, local-cohomology

In "Differential operators on the flag varieties" (http://www.numdam.org/article/AST_1981__87-88__43_0.pdf) by Brylinski, he uses on page 53 a Künneth formula for local cohomology with support.

Unfortunately he gives no reference for the formula and so far I couldn't find any literature stating this theorem.

Does anyone know what the general statement is and where I could find it?

EDIT: I removed my guess for the formula.

Comment: I am confused. What is $Z\cap V_1$? Note that $V_1$ does *not* embed canonically into $V_1\times V_2$.

Comment: That's a good point. Then I was too sloppy and I'm uncertain how the formula looks like. I will edit my question.

Comment: Did you check Bredon's "Sheaf Theory"? This is where a very general Künneth formula can be found.